# Invalid IP parameter on nginx setup

Tags: ip, webserver, nginx

I'm currently setting up an an nginx web server with PHP on ubuntu 10.x lastest. I've set it so it will only use my local LAN for testing but it comes with invalid paramter for `192.xxx.x.0/142`. My IP is near the end of this range but how can i write this to be valid? There appears to be no syntax documentation on this from searching. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to restrict IPs to your local LAN, you're attempting to disallow requests originating outside your subnet. To do this, you describe a base IP and subnet mask which together define a prefix and variable part of allowed addresses. Addresses in the subnet must start with the sequence of bits not masked out by the subnet mask. Many home networks use the address space `192.168.0.[0-255]`, which has a base address of `192.168.0.0` (the last octet doesn't matter because it will be masked out), and a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`.

The notation you're using combines the IP and subnet mask by just marking the IP, followed by a slash and the number of bits in the subnet mask. Thus, the shorthand for the subnet above is `192.168.0.0/24`. From here, you can see that your error is the `/142` at the end of the IP. IPv4 addresses are 32 bits long, and so a 142-bit subnet mask doesn't make much sense (even if it were capped at 32 bits, you would end up with a network of only one address!). From your notation, I assume the `xxx.x` in the middle two octets of your address are constant across your network, so you would just want to change 142 to 24.

For additional detail, you can read about Classless Inter-Domain Routing ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632#page-3)).